# How I can update my react project in a running server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apache2, digital-ocean

I am running a react application on a VPS digital-ocean server. My friend and I are doing this project. He updated some code and I replaced those updated files with FileZilla. After updating, I restarted `service apache2 restart` the apache server but those changes are not showing on that webpage.
Is there anything I am missing? Please help, I am new and Thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you rebuild your project and upload those files ?

Comment: Yes, I rebuilt the project on my local computer and then replaced it on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem,
First Replace Your Content that you have changed recently.
After replacing content with FileZilla
I have gone into my project file `cd /var/www/html/project-react` then run this command `sudo npm run build`  and then `service apache2 restart` and it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).